# debugging Python conditional statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I am attempting to make the python code to stop sending to the main_branch and instead keep searching for the exact branch that is located within it's own region. The  problem is that code only sends it to the branch when the branch is 'open'(or in another easy term is live), but when the branch is 'closed' (offline) it will make it send the item to the main_branch but the intention is to keep searching for the exact branch in intervals of 10 seconds until the branch opens (goes live). Here is what I have now:

```
address_data = self.get_address_data()
branchAddress = address_data.get("branch")
log.trace("{0!r}".format(address_data))
if branchAddress:
    branch_name = []
    # create a list of all available branch addresses
    for b in branchAddress:
        branch_name += [(b["company"]["postal_code"], b["company"]["shipment_item"])]

    log.info("Available addresses: {0}".format(", ".join(
        ["{0} ({1})".format(k, v) for k, v in branch_name])))

    # check if the address is valid,
    # if not search for address from available branches in the list
    if (self.get_option("branch")
            and not self.get_option("branch") in [v[0] for v in branch_name]):

        # print the main branch as 0
        log.info("0 - {0} ({1})".format(
            address_data["main_branch"]["company"]["postal_code"],
            address_data["main_branch"]["company"]["shipment_item"]))
        # print all other branches
        for i, item in enumerate(branch_name, start=1):
            log.info("{0} - {1} ({2})".format(i, item[0], item[1]))
        ###############################
        #What needs to be done: keep a constant look for the exact branch.
        #Problem: when branch is still 'closed', it automatically ships it back
        #to the Main branch instead of keeping the search on the branches for an exact match
        for c in branch_name:
            if c["company"]["postal_code"] == self.get_option("branch"):
                # if someone recently added during the time the Shipment software
                # was used, the item might not be in the JSON data
                item_purchase = b.get("item_purchase")
                if item_purchase:
                return self.item_address(item_purchase["warehouse"])
            else:
                log.info("no match found, will begin searching in 10 seconds")
                time.sleep(10)
                continue
        log.info("Wait 10 seconds")
        time.sleep(10)

        ###############################
# ship to branch address
if branchAddress and self.get_option("branch"):
    for b in branchAddress:
        if b["company"]["postal_code"] == self.get_option("branch"):
            # if someone recently added during the time the Shipment software
            # was used, the item might not be in the JSON data
            item_purchase = b.get("item_purchase")
            if item_purchase:
                return self.item_address(item_purchase["warehouse"])

# ignore the main branch stream, if a branch is selected
# or use it when there are no other branchAddress
if not self.get_option("branch") or not branchAddress:
      return self.item_address(address_data["main_branch"]["item_purchase"]["warehouse"])
```

My attempt is the block of code between the ########## lines, but after awhile, I realized that maybe I don't need it since the problem might be located somewhere else in this section of code. I assume the problem is one of the conditional statement mainly the last one **if not self.get_option("branch") or not branchAddress:** but I am not sure what to change as someone else coded this section and not me.

EDIT: Not sure if this will help but here's what happens. The Main branch is always open first before the rest of the branches will be opening up. Within the Main branch available list of branches are the south, west, east. But if the intended search was for the north branch which is offline, it sends it to the main branch. I am attempting to instead try looking for the north branch in an interval until it finally shows in the available list of branches.

Comment: FYI: You don't need `continue` at the end of a loop. That's what happens by default.

Comment: `return self.item_address(item_purchase["warehouse"])` exits the entire function, the remaining `if` statements are not executed. You probably want `break` to just end the loop, not the whole function.

Comment: You're printing `no match found` on every iteration of the loop until you find the matching branch. You should only print that if you get to the end of the loop without finding a match.

Comment: There's nothing in the code that refers to `open` or `closed` branches.

Comment: The 'continue' is cause I have 'return' just for me to see that it does do continue. Also I forgot to add an indent on the return which I just added now for the "return self.item_address(item_purchase["warehouse"])". The reason for the 'no match found' being inside of the loop is just for confirmation until I solve the solution, I plan to remove it later. The 'open' and 'closed' branches is actually when a branch store opened and have there side of the software functioning.  @Barmar

Comment: The 'open' actually means when the store branch opens and has their side of the software running. The problem occurs when they are currently closed and their side of the software is offline. Instead of searching until the business on the branch 'opens' it sends the item instead to the main branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem and was only able to confirm after a trial test run of a branch store opening up later than a shipment order being made.

It was the last conditional statement where I just had to replace conditional statement by editing this
**if not self.get_option("branch") or not branchAddress:**
to this:
**if not self.get_option("branch")**

the "or not branchAddress:" makes it true which caused the the shipment to go to the main branch store instead of looping back the code to where it tries to match the list once more.